# Xcode plugins and simulators disappeared after updating IDE

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6.3

I use Xcode for iOS Development. I had Alcatraz plugin and some another formatting plugins installed on my **Xcode 6.1**. After updating IDE to **6.3** they are disappeared. Also I've got new simulators **iOS 8.3** but I want still use **iOS 8.1**, **8.0** and even **7.1**, **7.0** too. They were installed but now they are not. I have downloaded all data back manually but there are new updates at this moment, Xcode 7 is coming.

Was it a Xcode bug or it's normal?
If there a way to keep plugins and simulators after update?